# How to use Custom HTTP request and paginations, sort, search in Vue 2.x

Tags: gridjs

I am an engineer who makes web systems in Tokyo.

I'm making a search system using Grid.js, but I faced a problem.
I don't know the solution because it's not in the documentation.

Since this system uses Vue 2.x, it uses axios.post with Custom HTTP Requset.
I was able to get the list, but I'm having trouble implementing sorting, pagination, and keyword search.

I want to send parameters by Post request.

Please tell me how to implement this.

The code is below

```js
    data() {
        return {
            columns: [
                {name: 'user name', id: 'user_name'},
                {name: 'email', id: 'email'},
            ],
            page: {
                enabled: true,
                limit:  100,
                server: {
                    body: (prev, page) => {
                        console.log(page) // OK, show page number 0,1,2...
                        return {
                            page: page
                        }
                    }
                },
            },
            sort: {
            },
            search: {
                server: {
                    // url: (prev, keyword) => `${prev}?q=${keyword}`
                    // what's this.
                }
            },
            server: {
                url: '/api/v2/users/list',
                method: 'POST',
                async data (opt) {
                    let response = await axios.post(opt.url)
                    return {
                        data: response.data.results.map(item => {
                            return {
                                username: item.username,
                                email: item.email,
                            }
                        }),
                        total: response.data.count,
                    }
                }
            },
        };
```

Answer (score 0):

OK.
Set POST payload this.

```js
    data() {
        return {
            columns: [
                {name: 'user name', id: 'user_name'},
                {name: 'email', id: 'email'},
            ],
            page: {
                enabled: true,
                limit:  100,
                server: {
                    body: (prev, page) => {
                        console.log(page) // OK, show page number 0,1,2...
                        return {
                            page: page
                        }
                    }
                },
            },
            sort: {
            },
            search: {
                server: {
                    // url: (prev, keyword) => `${prev}?q=${keyword}`
                    // what's this.
                }
            },
            server: {
                url: '/api/v2/users/list',
                method: 'POST',
                body: {},
                async data (opt) {
                    let response = await axios.post(opt.url)
                    return {
                        data: response.data.results.map(item => {
                            return {
                                username: item.username,
                                email: item.email,
                            }
                        }),
                        total: response.data.count,
                    }
                }
            },
        };
```